# Using toLowercase and includes with an array for response message

Tags: discord.js

I'd like to have an array with declared phrases but need to find a way for the responseObject to look for messages using toLowercase() and includes

```
if(responseObject[message.content]) {
   message.reply(responseObject[message.content]);
}
```

Declared values are

```
const responseObject = {
  "AMD": "AMD has no value.",
  "no balls": "what?",
  "took profit": "good boy"
}
```

Comment: Hello. Could you please clarify what is your question because I don't really understand it. :)

Comment: please avoid profanity in your examples. This is a professional site. I have edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be not Case-Sensitive anymore just do:

```
if(responseObject[message.content.toLowerCase()]) {
   message.reply(responseObject[message.content.toLowerCase()]);
}
```